# In Diabelli's "Duet in D" for piano, what are these brackets on chords that look like vertical slurs?

Tags: piano, notation

While working through 'Duet in D' for piano, by A. Diabelli, I came across this unfamiliar notation that looks like a slur  between two notes of the same chord or some kind of bracket (see below). What is this notation called, and how do I read it?

[image: Bar 112 of Diabelli's 'Duet in D']

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's an alternate way to notate an arpeggio.

> arpège (Fr.), arpeggio (It.), arpeggi (It. plural): (Italian, meaning 'in the manner of a harp') a spread chord played from the top down or from the bottom up indicated by a vertical wavy line, a vertical square bracket or **a curved bracket** (the latter two signs are now uncommon).

(Direct quote from [Dolmetsch](https://dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm). Always a great place to start when looking for music symbols)

[image]

Comment: If the notes aren't supposed to be played at the same time, why are they on top of one another? Is the arpeggio too fast to be written correctly otherwise?

Comment: usually yes, but not necessarily. arpeggios can be played slow too and, secondly, there is much freedom in playing arpeggios. up/down, add notes, hold certain notes, play some notes more often... arpeggi are embalishements like trillo, mordent, they too are only notated as a symbol.